# Adding animations using Bootstrap events

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a small difficulty with the Bootstrap tabs.

Basically I am using these tabs for a demo site and I have the following HTML structure.

HTML :

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab">
                <li class="active"><a href="#sectionA">General fitness</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sectionB">Cardio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sectionC">weight training</a></li>
                <li><a href="#sectionD">weight loss</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div id="sectionA" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 clearfix">
                                <img src="images/traning/traning-image.jpg" alt="stretching exercise" class="pull-right animated bounceInLeft">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5 animated bounceInRight" >
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus eligendi odit aspernatur asperiores quia laudantium porro velit. Eligendi neque, quos quo at eos earum qui harum, temporibus dolore laboriosam aperiam.</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="sectionB" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 clearfix">
                                <img src="images/traning/traning-image.jpg" alt="stretching exercise" class="pull-right">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5" >
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus eligendi odit aspernatur asperiores quia laudantium porro velit. Eligendi neque, quos quo at eos earum qui harum, temporibus dolore laboriosam aperiam.</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="sectionC" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 clearfix">
                                <img src="images/traning/traning-image.jpg" alt="stretching exercise" class="pull-right">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5" >
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus eligendi odit aspernatur asperiores quia laudantium porro velit. Eligendi neque, quos quo at eos earum qui harum, temporibus dolore laboriosam aperiam.</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="sectionD" class="tab-pane fade">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 clearfix">
                                <img src="images/traning/traning-image.jpg" alt="stretching exercise" class="pull-right">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-5" >
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus eligendi odit aspernatur asperiores quia laudantium porro velit. Eligendi neque, quos quo at eos earum qui harum, temporibus dolore laboriosam aperiam.</p>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Now this works perfectly fine, I have used this tabs feature for a lot of old sites of mine, but this time I decided to add some css-3 animations, so let's focus on the part that I am having difficulty with. Basically, every time a tab is clicked I want the `<img>` and the `<div class="col-md-5">` to be added with the classes `animated bounceInLeft` and `animated bounceInRight` respectively.

Now, what did I do to achieve this, basically every time the tabs are clicked an event fires, `hidden.bs.tab` and every time a tab is shown an event fires `shown.bs.tab`. Now I wrote the below code :

```
$('#myTab').on('hidden.bs.tab'  , function(){
    // console.log('tab hidden');
    $('.tab-content img').removeClass('animated bounceInLeft');
    $('.tab-content .col-md-5').removeClass('animated bounceInRight');
});

$('#myTab').on('shown.bs.tab' , function(){
    // console.log('tab hidden');
      if ($('.tab-pane').hasClass('active')) {
      $('.tab-content img' ).addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
      $('.tab-content .col-md-5').addClass('animated bounceInRight');          
    }
});
```

There is a big flaw with the above code I have written though, what I wanted to achieve is when I click on a tab I only want the `<img>` and the `<div class="col-md-5">` of that particular tab to be added with the classes `animated bounceInLeft` and `animated bounceInRight` respectively. But what the above code is really doing is removing the classes from all the elements and immediately re-adding them.

I am thinking the `this` keyword maybe needs to be used, but am I not sure how to implement this; can somebody tell me what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if Bootstrap has animated classes?
However you could use [this repo](https://github.com/daneden/animate.css) to achieve the preferred animation you want.

Add this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="animate.min.css">
```

I've updated the HTML slightly(added class text-content to every col-md-5).

```
<div id="sectionD" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-5 clearfix">
              <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="stretching exercise" class="pull-right">
           </div>
           <div class="col-md-5 text-content">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Delectus eligendi odit aspernatur asperiores quia laudantium porro velit. Eligendi neque, quos quo at eos earum qui harum, temporibus dolore laboriosam aperiam.</p>
           </div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

And this jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    //make first tab active
    $("#myTab li:eq(0) a").tab('show');

    $('#myTab').on('hidden.bs.tab'  , function(){
        $('.text-content').removeClass('animated bounceInRight');
        $('img').removeClass('animated bounceInLeft');
    });

    $('#myTab').on('shown.bs.tab' , function(){
        $('.active').find('.text-content').addClass('animated bounceInRight');
        $('.active').find('img').addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
    });

});
```

Comment: i have used the animations very much from the same repo ;) , thanks for ur answer .

Answer (score 0):

Using a little `setTimeout` magic, I found the solution:

```
$('#myTab').on('click' , 'li a' , function(){

    $this = $(this);
    var str_href = $this.attr('href'); 

      str_image      = str_href + ' ' + 'img';
      str_contentdiv = str_href + ' ' + '.add-animation';


      setTimeout(function(){
          $(str_image).addClass('animated bounceInLeft');
          $(str_contentdiv).addClass('animated bounceInRight'); 

           setTimeout( function(){
              $(str_image).removeClass('animated bounceInLeft');
              $(str_contentdiv).removeClass('animated bounceInRight');
           }, 2000);
      }, 100);  

});
```

Note: to the col-md-5 that I add the animated bounceInRight class I also add the class `add-animation` as a hook, could have used a css selector, but never mind.

**Drawback of this method** : if the user turns out to be a click maniac, the animations will not show, because that's the way `setTimeout` works :D